# About development using android camera

Tags: android, kotlin, camera

I'm trying to develop application that using the MediaRecorder API that runs on HMT-1.
Android Studio is used for development, and the operating environment is Android 10 or higher.

While shooting a video using the MediaRecoder API, we are verifying whether the same microphone can be used in another process such as the SpeechRecognizer API.

Recording processing alone with the MediaRecoder API and voice input alone with the SpeechRecognizer API can be performed without problems.
However, if you try to record and input voice at the same time, an error will occur.

If you want to use the input voice for multiple processes, please let me know if you have any reference documents or samples.

MediaRecorder settings.

```
    path = getExternalFilesDir(null)!!.path

    mMediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()

    mMediaRecorder!!.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
    mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
    mMediaRecorder!!.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
    mMediaRecorder!!.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
    mMediaRecorder!!.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16)
    mMediaRecorder!!.setAudioSamplingRate(44100)
    mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoSize(1024, 768)
    mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
    mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000)
    mMediaRecorder!!.setOutputFile(path + "/" + DateFormat.format("yyyyMMdd'-'kkmmss", Calendar.getInstance()) + ".mp4")
    mMediaRecorder!!.setOnInfoListener(this)
    mMediaRecorder!!.setMaxDuration(VIDEO_DURATION)
    mMediaRecorder!!.setMaxFileSize(VIDEO_FILESIZE)
    mMediaRecorder!!.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder!!.surface)
    val rotation = (getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager)
    if(rotation.defaultDisplay.rotation == 2){
        mMediaRecorder!!.setOrientationHint(180)
    }

    mMediaRecorder!!.prepare()

    try {
        mMediaRecorder!!.start()
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        mMediaRecorder!!.release()
    }
```

SpeechRecognizer settings.

```
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(applicationContext)
    mSpeechRecognizer?.setRecognitionListener(createRecognitionListenerStringStream { recognize_text_view.text = it })

    public fun onStart(View: View){
        mSpeechRecognizer?.startListening(Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH))
    }

    public fun onStop(View: View){
        mSpeechRecognizer?.stopListening()
    }
```

Comment: The microphone is a single resource.  It can be owned by only 1 app at a time.  That means you can't have multiple processes listening in. This includes speech recognition.

Comment: My question has been resolved, thank you.